# Differentiating unit tangent vector does not work

Tags: manipulate, vector, vector-calculus

I am new to Mathematica and I want to visualize the tangent and normal vector field of a particular embedding of the circle. In my code it is [CapitalGamma][s]. When I put the unit tangent vector (uT[s]) in Arrow[{}] I can manipulate a point with the corresponding unit tangent vector along my embedding but when I replace it with the unit normal (uN[s]) as I have defined it I get the following error:

Coordinate {0.4387912809451864 + (Abs[-0.8775825618903728 - 0.42073549240394825 `Derivative[1][Norm][{-0.2397127693021015, 0.4387912809451864}]]^2 + Abs[-0.479425538604203 + 0.42073549240394825` Derivative[1][Norm][{-0.2397127693021015, 0.4387912809451864}]]^2)^Rat should be a pair of numbers, or a Scaled or Offset form.

Why is this happening? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

````
a = \[Pi]
c = \[Pi]/16
\[Rho] = 1/2
r[s_] := Piecewise[{{Sqrt[\[Rho]^2 - (s + a - \[Rho] - c)^2], 
    s <= -a + \[Rho] + c}, {\[Rho], -a + \[Rho] + c <= s <= 
     a - \[Rho] - c}, {Sqrt[\[Rho]^2 - (s - a + \[Rho] + c)^2], 
    s >= a - \[Rho] - c}}]

p[s_] := {Cos[s], Sin[s]}
n[s_] := {-Cos[s], -Sin[s]}

\[CapitalGamma][s_] := 
 Piecewise[{{p[s] + r[s]*n[s], 
    s <= a - c}, {p[2*a - 2*c - s] - 
     r[2*a - 2*c - s]*n[2*a - 2*c - s], s >= a - c}}]

uT[s_] := \[CapitalGamma]'[s]/Norm[\[CapitalGamma]'[s]]
uN[s_] := T'[s]/Norm[T'[s]]

Manipulate[
 Show[ParametricPlot[\[CapitalGamma][s], {s, -a + c, 3*a - 3*c}, 
   MaxRecursion -> 10, PlotPoints -> 60, Exclusions -> None], 
  AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
  Epilog -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[6], Point[\[CapitalGamma][s]], 
    Arrow[{\[CapitalGamma][s], \[CapitalGamma][s] + 
       uT[s]}]}], {{s, .5}, -a + c, 3*a - 3*c, .01, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```
````

Comment: Mathematica v12.2 evaluates your code without problems. Perhaps restart your kernel and rerun your code

Comment: T[s] is not defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `Norm` contain `Abs` and `Abs` is a function of a complex variable and is therefore not differentiable, we can replace `Norm[v]` to `Sqrt[v.v]`.

That is  we set ( we also set  `PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"` and remove `MaxRecursion -> 10`).

```
Clear["Global`*"];
uT[s_] := Γ'[s]/Sqrt[Γ'[s] . Γ'[s]]

uN[s_] := uT'[s]/Sqrt[uT'[s] . uT'[s]]
```

```
a = π;
c = π/16;
ρ = 1/2;
r[s_] := 
 Piecewise[{{Sqrt[ρ^2 - (s + a - ρ - c)^2], 
    s <= -a + ρ + c}, {ρ, -a + ρ + c <= s <= 
     a - ρ - c}, {Sqrt[ρ^2 - (s - a + ρ + c)^2], 
    s >= a - ρ - c}}]
p[s_] := {Cos[s], Sin[s]}
n[s_] := {-Cos[s], -Sin[s]}
Γ[s_] := 
 Piecewise[{{p[s] + r[s]*n[s], 
    s <= a - c}, {p[2*a - 2*c - s] - 
     r[2*a - 2*c - s]*n[2*a - 2*c - s], s >= a - c}}]
uT[s_] := Γ'[s]/
  Sqrt[Γ'[s] . Γ'[s]]
uN[s_] := uT'[s]/Sqrt[uT'[s] . uT'[s]]
Manipulate[
 Show[ParametricPlot[Γ[s], {s, -a + c, 3*a - 3*c}, 
   PlotPoints -> 60, Exclusions -> None, 
   PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"], AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
  Epilog -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[6], Point[Γ[s]], 
    Arrow[{Γ[s], Γ[s] + 
       uN[s]}]}], {{s, .5}, -a + c, 3*a - 3*c, .01, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]